# Storing a User Provided Date in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I've got this schema:

```
var imageSchema = new Schema( {
  caption: {type: String, required: true},
  url: {type: String, required: true}
});


var EventSchema = new Schema({

  name: {type: String, required: true},
  date: {type: Date, required: true},
  time: {type: String, required: true},
  location: {type: String, required: true},
  description: { type: String, required: false },
  image: {type: String, required: false},
  images: [imageSchema]


});
```

Requests are handled via locomotive.js, and the controller action for creating new records looks like this:

```
EventController.create = function() {
  if(preScreen.screen.bind(this)("event", "create")) {
    this.elements = modelHelper.loadValues.bind(this)();

    this.saveMessage = "Save";
    this.strings = strings;

    if(this.req.method && this.req.method == "POST") 
    { 
        this._createEvent();
    } else {
        this.render();
    }
  } else {
    this.redirect(this.urlFor({controller: "dashboard", action: "error"}));
  }
};
```

This is a fairly standard action controller; mostly invoking an input view or or handling the _create when the received with a POST header.

the _createEvent function looks like this:

```
EventController._createEvent = function() {
  if(!(this.elements)) this.elements = require('../templates/Event/elements')();
  if(!(this.event)) this.event = new Event(); 

  modelHelper.populate.bind(this)(this.elements, "event",  function() {
    modelHelper.save.bind(this)("event", this._confirm.bind(this), "create");
  }.bind(this));
};
```

For my models I encapsulate all of the inputs in a template pattern.    Rather than spend a lot of time on the framework around this (which I am working on releasing open source once I have finished doing small tweaks too)  I will say that effectively the template contains one element for each path in the schema and provides some client-side details (error messages, labels etc.) these template objects are used by a modelHelper object which is fairly agnostic.  Effectively what modelHelper.populate does is inspect the "type" property of each object within elements, and calls a handler for the appropriate input type.

the handler for date types is:

```
    case "date" :
    this[record][field.name] = strings.exists(this.param(field)) ?
            strings.trim(this.param(field.name)) : null;

    break;
```

although I've also tried strings.trim(Date.parse(this.param(field.name)) to get the UTC Timestamp from the user string.

I've been able to validate that the user entered date string does return a valid UTC stamp by using console.log within the date parser.

When the modelHelper.save() call is made it runs through these template objects, creates an associate array with the values picked up from the parsers and passes it to Record.save().

Most of this has been thoroughly tested and is being used in production however this is my first scenario where I am using dates other than date.now() as a default value.

What is the correct body for the date parser in order for mongodb/ the mongoose driver to push a date into a Date type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any string that JavaScript's [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method can parse will work as the string is cast to a `Date` by Mongoose using [this function](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema/date.js#L94) which calls the `Date` [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) which uses `Date.parse` to parse strings.

Comment: the Github link is not pointing to the correct line anymore, since its content changed. I recommend you use permanent links.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway, it was helpful!